# AmCharts - Redondeo decimal de la media

Tags: javascript, redondeo, amcharts

Estoy trabajando con AmCharts.
Mi gráfico está totalmente funcional, y quiero que el valor de la mediana se muestre. Aquí pongo mi código:

```
"graphs": 
 [
   {
     "title": "Total Open Ratio %",
     "valueField": "def",
     "type": "line",
     "fillAlphas": 0.2,
     "legendPeriodValueText": "Average: [[value.average]] %",
     "legendValueText": "[[value]] %",
     "lineColor" : "#26a69a",
     "lineColorField": "lineColor",
     "balloonText": "<b>[[title]]</b><br>[[value]] %",                    
     "lineThickness": 1,
   }
 ],
```

Reference:
https://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/AmGraph

Todo funciona perfectamente, pero el valor de la mediana es demasiado largo:
[image: Example of Average value]
¿Alguien sabe como usar solo los dos primeros decimales como: 19.41 % en vez de  19.41051724137931 % ?

Comment: Hi, this is stack Overflow in Spanish, please transelate your Question or use this (site)[http://stackoverflow.com/]

Comment: Arreglado, siento la confusión, gracias!

Comment: Aunque no conozco ese tipo de graficas, haz probado colocar esto en el campo average `[[value.average.toFixed(2)]]` o donde se calcula ese `value.average` ponerle el `.toFixed`

Comment: @WilfredoP gracias por tu aporte. Si uso esto no detecta bien el valor y me da error NaN. Y tampoco funciona [[value.average]].toFixed(2), lo coge como string, añado más abajo como lo he solucionado.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depende del tipo de gráfico que uses, pero [`AMChart`](https://docs.amcharts.com/javascriptcharts/AmChart) (el abstracto del que todos heredan y no puede ser instanciado) tiene dos propiedades que te servirán:

## numberFormatter

```
Object  {precision:-1, decimalSeparator:'.', thousandsSeparator:','}
```

> Objeto para formatear números. `Precision = -1` significa que los valores no van a ser redondeados

## percentFormatter

```
Object  {precision:2, decimalSeparator:'.', thousandsSeparator:','}
```

> Objeto con `precision`, `decimalSeparator` y `separadorDeMiles` previamente definidos para formatear porcentajes.

---

Eso si, no he sido capaz de encontrar ejemplos prácticos donde expliquen su uso...

Comment: Gracias, me ha servido, he añadido como lo he arreglado más abajo!

Comment: grande, me alegro que lo hayas solucionado! :)

Answer (score 1):

Gracias por vuestros aportes. Añado como lo he arreglado.
Habría usado percentFormatter pero al no estarlo pasando como porcentaje me va mejor así.

```
var chart = AmCharts.makeChart( "chart_opens_def", {
 "type": "serial",
        [...]
         "numberFormatter": 
        {
            "precision": 2,
            "decimalSeparator": ".",
            "thousandsSeparator": ","
        },   
"graphs": 
        [
          {
            "title": "Total Open Ratio %",
            "valueField": "def",
            "type": "line",
            "fillAlphas": 0.2,
            "legendPeriodValueText": "Average: [[value.average]] %",
            "legendValueText": "[[value]]",
            "lineColor" : "#26a69a",
            "lineColorField": "lineColor",
            "balloonText": "<b>[[title]]</b><br>[[value]]",                    
            "lineThickness": 1,
          }
       ],
       [...]
```

Gracias!!